# Get content and image from RSS url in django-yarr

Tags: django, rss-reader

I'm using django-yarr for my RSS reader applications. Is there any way to fetch content from RSS URL and save in database? Or is there any library that could do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to read data from an RSS, process it and save it?

Use [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to fetch the data.

```
import requests

req = requests.get('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/technology/rss.xml')
reg.text // XML as a string
```

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to process the data (or similar libraries that can process xml)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text)

images = soup.findAll('media:thumbnail')
```

Finally do whatever you want with the data

```
for image in images:
    thing = DjangoModelThing()
    thing.image = image.attrs.get('url')
    thing.save()
```

**UPDATE**

Alternatively you could grab each article from the RSS

```
articles = soup.findAll('item')

for article in articles:
    title = article.find('title')
    description = article.find('description')
    link = article.find('link')
    images = article.find('media:thumbnail')
```

Comment: consider this link in rss : http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-26985818#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa,  I want images and content in this link.

Comment: That isn't a url to RSS.  Are you looking to find that article in a given RSS feed or do you only have the url to the HTML?
The difference being if you are scraping RSS(XML) or HTML.  They are similar processes but HTML is prone to change.